# Cannot get data to update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Newbie Q: I have existing data painting to the Edit screen.. but cannot get it to update.  I can create and list(in other code), but doing something wrong on the update.  I believe I am doing something wrong in the controller.. Save button actions back to Edit screen with no changes.

Controller Code:

```
     public class CompeditorController : Controller
     {

         private readonly BodyBuilderDB _db;
         public CompeditorController(BodyBuilderDB db)
         {
             _db = db;
         }
[HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Edit(int CompeditorId)
    {
        var model = _db.Compeditors.Single(d => d.CompeditorId == CompeditorId);
        return View(model);
    }


[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Change(EditCompViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var compeditor = new Compeditor();
        var bodybuilderDB = _db.Compeditors;         
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)

            compeditor.CompeditorId = viewModel.CompeditorId;
            compeditor.FirstName = viewModel.FirstName;
            compeditor.MiddleInt = viewModel.MiddleInt;
            compeditor.LastName = viewModel.LastName;
            compeditor.StreetAddress = viewModel.StreetAddress;
            compeditor.City = viewModel.City;
            compeditor.State = viewModel.State;
            compeditor.PostalCode = viewModel.PostalCode;
            compeditor.HomePhone = viewModel.HomePhone;
            compeditor.CellPhone = viewModel.CellPhone;
            compeditor.Height = viewModel.Height;
            compeditor.Weight = viewModel.Weight;
            compeditor.EmailAddress = viewModel.EmailAddress;

            _db.Entry(bodybuilderDB).CurrentValues.SetValues(compeditor);
            _db.SaveChanges();

        }
```

End of View Code:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Weight)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Weight)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Weight)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Model:

```
    using System;
    using eManager.Core;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

 namespace eManager.Web2.Models
 {
     public class EditCompViewModel
    {
    [Key]
    public int CompeditorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleInt { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Height { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Weight { get; set; }

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this before your Save Changes

```
_db.Entry(bodybuilderDB).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Remove

```
var compeditor = new Compeditor();
        compeditor.CompeditorId = viewModel.CompeditorId;
        compeditor.FirstName = viewModel.FirstName;
        compeditor.MiddleInt = viewModel.MiddleInt;
        compeditor.LastName = viewModel.LastName;
        compeditor.StreetAddress = viewModel.StreetAddress;
        compeditor.City = viewModel.City;
        compeditor.State = viewModel.State;
        compeditor.PostalCode = viewModel.PostalCode;
        compeditor.HomePhone = viewModel.HomePhone;
        compeditor.CellPhone = viewModel.CellPhone;
        compeditor.Height = viewModel.Height;
        compeditor.Weight = viewModel.Weight;
        compeditor.EmailAddress = viewModel.EmailAddress;
```

And change

```
 _db.Entry(bodybuilderDB).CurrentValues.SetValues(compeditor);
```

To

```
 _db.Entry(bodybuilderDB).CurrentValues.SetValues(viewModel);
```

Comment: Hmm I get the same result.  Data is pulled into the edit screen and when I modify any value, the screen repaints with the original data.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: here is where I did the change:  compeditor.Weight = ewModel.Weight;
                compeditor.EmailAddress = viewModel.EmailAddress;
              _db.Entry(bodybuilderDB).CurrentValues.SetValues(compeditor);
_db.Entry(bodybuilderDB).State = EntityState.Modified;
_db.SaveChanges();

            }

Comment: Just added the current code to the edit.. (still learning stackoverflow as well)  Still not getting to the db